# Does every expression in C make a copy of the variables?

Tags: c, rvalue, lvalue

I'm trying to understand R-values and L-values when it comes to expressions in C and I know that many expressions are not valid L-values because the address of the end result is not known. This is because in many instances, a copy of the variables is used in the expression and so the address of the copy is not known. For example,

```
    char ch = 'a';
    char *p = &ch;
    p + 1; //This expression can be used as an R-value, but not an L-value
```

I believe what is happening (please correct me if I'm wrong) in the expression is that a copy of p is created, 1 is added to that copy so that p+1 points at the char after ch, but the address of this new p+1 pointer is not known, so it can't be used as an L-value.

Does this behavior of making a copy of the variables and using the copies in the expression happen for all expressions in C? For example, if I have

```
    int a = 100;
    int b = 25;
    a - b;
```

Is a copy of variable a created (and stored at an unknown location) and a copy of variable b created (the copy of b is also stored at an unknown location), the data in the copies is used to subtract and then the result is stored in another unknown location or is the data taken from the original variables, subtracted and then the result is stored at an unknown location?

Comment: in your last paragraph both options are the same

Answer (score 2):

> Does every expression in C make a copy of the variables?

It doesn't really matter.

The compiler has optimization. Compiler is able to do anything with the code, as long as side effects are the same. In your examples `p + 1;` and `a - b;` are doing nothing, they can be optimized out by the compiler, so nothing happens.

What happens on a actual machine with the code generated by the compiler is highly machine specific. Compiler can first load the values of variables to some registers, then perform computation on these registers - or may not, may perform computation on values as they are stored, or may not even reserve any memory for the variables.

> I know that many expressions are not valid L-values because the address of the end 
>   result is not known

That could be the underlying reason you could make to justify that, but the rules are just more direct. C standard just lists operators and says that [the result of `+` is a value](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.3p2) or [the result of `*` is a lvalue](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p4). There is no "generic" rule.

> Does this behavior of making a copy of the variables and using the copies in the expression happen for all expressions in C?

C standard doesn't talk about "variables" or "copies of variables", C standard talks about "values". An expression has a defined value, defined end result. C standard doesn't concern really how the compiler will arrive at that value. So the actual behavior can be anything. If a particular compiler decides to make a copy of the variables or decides not to - good for him, as long as the end results are correct.

*lvalue* is something that can be on the left side of `=` operator. Not necessarily it is a variable, for example `((char*)0x01)[1]` is a *lvalue* although it's a result of some operators. *rvalue* (or just *value*) is a value that you can't assign to.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of such calculations are not standard so they can be different in different compilers. The important thing to understand is that R-values represent **temporary values**. It can be a register or some allocated memory.

Calculations are made in the CPU on registers. So, the compiler will move the value of the variables in to registers and than will calculate the subtraction. 
this is an assembly of such a calculation:

```
 659:   c7 45 f8 64 00 00 00    movl   $0x64,-0x8(%rbp)
 660:   c7 45 fc 19 00 00 00    movl   $0x19,-0x4(%rbp)
 667:   8b 45 f8                mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
 66a:   2b 45 fc                sub    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
```

You can see that the values 100(64 in hex) and 25(19 in hex) are saved on the stack at addresses relative to base pointer(-0x8, -0x4 respectively).
than the value from -0x8 is moved into the eax register and the value from -0x4 is subtracted from the value in the register and stored in the register itself.

As you can see, the result will end up in a register, so it doesn't have an address at the memory.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C11 standard(ISO-IEC-9899-2011)--6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays and function designators:

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the unary & operator, the ++
> operator, the -- operator, or the left operand of the . operator or an assignment operator,
> an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored in the designated
> object (and is no longer an lvalue); this is called lvalue conversion.